# Javascript onclick Function call prompts for syntax error on passing the string as parameter

Tags: javascript

I have javascript snippet which is iterating over a json object, snippet is shown below:

```
var msgTree = "";
    $.each(canMessage, function (key, value) {
        var i=0;
        $.each(value, function (k, v) {

            //console.log(k);
            msgTree += '<li class="has-children"><input type="checkbox" name="cat-'+i+'" id="cat-'+i+'"><label for="cat-'+i+'">'+k+'</label><ul>';

            i++;
            var j=0;
            // console.log(msgTree);
            $.each(v, function (r, p) {
                    // console.log(r);
                    msgTree += '<li> <a href="#0" id="msg-'+i+'0'+j+'" onclick="postMessageToCustomer('+p+')">'+r+'</a></li>';
                    j++;
            });
            msgTree += '</ul></li>';
        });
    });
    // console.log(msgTree);
    $('#canned-msg-tree').html(msgTree);
```

Now whenever the `onclick` event is executed the I get an error in console saying:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

and show me the actual function calling as :

```
postMessageToCustomer(I am sorry to hear that. Let me help you with the service request to make a device swop.)
```

can someone help me in understanding how can I make it read as a string in the code I have above?

Comment: You'll need quotes around the parameter e.g. `postMessageToCustomer("I am sorry to hear that. Let me help you with the service request to make a device swop.")`

Comment: @phuzi, yes I know that, but my every attempt for adding the quotes is throwing me another syntax error.. please suggest the way I should be putting the quotes

Comment: @OM The Eternity just FYI but you are iterating over an object, not a "JSON Object." JSON stands for javascript object notation and is the standard that defines how to convert an object into a string representation of that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click event is passing a string directly into the function. You need to encapsulate it in quotes.

```
msgTree += '<li> <a href="#0" id="msg-'+i+'0'+j+'" onclick="postMessageToCustomer(\''+p+'\')">'+r+'</a></li>';
```

You could also do this without relying on a text onclick attribute too. It is even easier since you are using jQuery already.

```
  var canMessage = {
     "Test": {
         "Line One": {
             "Sub Item": "My Message"
         }
     }
 };
var msgTree = $("#canned-msg-tree");
$.each(canMessage, function (key, value) {
    var i=0;
    $.each(value, function (k, v) {
        var item = $('<li class="has-children"><input type="checkbox" name="cat-'+i+'" id="cat-'+i+'"><label for="cat-'+i+'">'+k+'</label></li>');

        var subList = $("<ul>");
        var j=0;
        $.each(v, function (r, p) {
            var subItem = $('<li> <a href="#0" id="msg-'+i+'0'+j+'">'+r+'</a></li>');

            subItem.click(function (){
                postMessageToCustomer(p);
            });

            subList.append(subItem);
            j++;
        });
        item.append(subList);
        msgTree.append(item);
        i++;
    });
});
```

Comment: To whoever downvoted it would be nice if you commented with your reasoning

Comment: The reasoning is in my answer. Creating HTML by pasting together unsanitized strings is not something anyone should be recommending. Not only will it fail if the data contains " or ', it also is a significant security hole.

Comment: I agree and I wasn't recommending it. I was telling the OP why it was breaking.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this, use one of the many frameworks to build your html and attach listeners. Otherwise you'll have to implement all the sorts of special cases the frameworks already do. In your case, you are need to tell the interpreter it's a string by putting quotes around at, and as the string is unsanitized data you also have to escape it as a html attribute so that if it contains either the double quote marks you're using as attribute delemeters or the single quote marks for string delimiters then it will give an error. It's much simpler and more robust to use a framework for this instead. Almost any framework you choose will have this for you.

Comment: Informative.. will use it in some other case... as i have a very specific case of strings this time and that even a static one

Comment: @OM The Eternity any place you use a string you can also use a string to create actual DOM objects and register events the proper way.

Comment: @Marie the example would only be a useful answer to this question if it happened to be in whatever the OP is using. `$.each` exists in jQuery but could be something else, and the question is tagged javascript rather than with a framework.