# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input in HTML/PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, syntax-error

I'm having problems with the next code, exactly in the line when passing more than one parameter in the second button, which calls deleteEntry(). When passing only an argument, the first one, there is no problem. Both "$row[nombre]" and "$row[signo_solar] are strings.

```
echo "<td><button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='editEntry($row[id])'>Editar</button> <button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='deleteEntry($row[id],'$row[nombre]','$row[signo_solar]')'>Eliminar</button></td>";
                                echo "</tr>"
```

Here's a little bit of context of the code.

```
...
<tbody>
                        <?php
                        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, nombre, signo_solar FROM horoscopos")
                            or die (mysqli_error($conn));
                        
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($query)==0){
                            echo "<td colspan='3'>No hay horóscopos que mostrar. Prueba a añadir uno en 'Crear entrada' del menú superior.</td>";
                        }else{
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { // Mientras haya elementos en el array
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>$row[nombre]</td>";
                                echo "<td>$row[signo_solar]</td>";
                                // Al clickar editar, pasamos el id del elemento a editar con el fin de poder modificar la DB (id es la clave de la relación)
                                echo "<td><button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='editEntry($row[id])'>Editar</button> <button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='deleteEntry($row[id],'$row[nombre]','$row[signo_solar]')'>Eliminar</button></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
</tbody>
...
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "<td><button class='btn btn-danger' onclick=\"deleteEntry($row[id],'$row[nombre]','$row[signo_solar]')\">Eliminar</button></td>";
```

Comment: it did work! thank you. Whats the meaning of that change? What does it do? I'd like to understand what i'm doing.

Comment: You should include some description of what and why your change does to solve the problem.

Comment: "Your click event is passing a string directly into the function. You need to encapsulate it in quotes." see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754790/javascript-onclick-function-call-prompts-for-syntax-error-on-passing-the-string